# ERROR: Unexpected character with savefig in Julia

Tags: python, json, plotly, julia, savefig

I'm just trying to save a plot with savefig but I've encountered a strange ERROR.

```
julia> PlotlyJS.savefig(p)
ERROR: Unexpected character
Line: 0
Around: ...�Desea terminar el tra...
            ^

Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base .\error.jl:35
  [2] _error(message::String, ps::JSON.Parser.MemoryParserState)
    @ JSON.Parser C:\Users\Franco\.julia\packages\JSON\93Ea8\src\Parser.jl:140
  [3] parse_jsconstant(#unused#::JSON.Parser.ParserContext{Dict{String, Any}, Int64, true, nothing}, ps::JSON.Parser.MemoryParserState)      
    @ JSON.Parser C:\Users\Franco\.julia\packages\JSON\93Ea8\src\Parser.jl:193
  [4] parse_value(pc::JSON.Parser.ParserContext{Dict{String, Any}, Int64, true, nothing}, ps::JSON.Parser.MemoryParserState)
    @ JSON.Parser C:\Users\Franco\.julia\packages\JSON\93Ea8\src\Parser.jl:170
  [5] parse(str::String; dicttype::Type, inttype::Type{Int64}, allownan::Bool, null::Nothing) 
    @ JSON.Parser C:\Users\Franco\.julia\packages\JSON\93Ea8\src\Parser.jl:450
  [6] parse
    @ C:\Users\Franco\.julia\packages\JSON\93Ea8\src\Parser.jl:443 [inlined]
  [7] savefig(p::Plot{Vector{GenericTrace{Dict{Symbol, Any}}}, Layout{Dict{Symbol, Any}}, Vector{PlotlyFrame}}; width::Nothing, height::Nothing, scale::Nothing, format::String)
    @ PlotlyJS C:\Users\Franco\.julia\packages\PlotlyJS\Jj38U\src\kaleido.jl:104
  [8] savefig(p::Plot{Vector{GenericTrace{Dict{Symbol, Any}}}, Layout{Dict{Symbol, Any}}, Vector{PlotlyFrame}})
    @ PlotlyJS C:\Users\Franco\.julia\packages\PlotlyJS\Jj38U\src\kaleido.jl:73
  [9] savefig(p::PlotlyJS.SyncPlot; kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ PlotlyJS C:\Users\Franco\.julia\packages\PlotlyJS\Jj38U\src\kaleido.jl:71
 [10] savefig(p::PlotlyJS.SyncPlot)
    @ PlotlyJS C:\Users\Franco\.julia\packages\PlotlyJS\Jj38U\src\kaleido.jl:71
 [11] top-level scope
    @ REPL[56]:1
```

Can solve it updating packages or reinstalling packages. Don't know what happen :(.

EDIT: I'm trying to save a contour plot that comes from a function

```
p = employment_contour(results)
```

But I have tried doing it step by step and, as expected, it doesn't work either. "results" is a matrix.

Comment: Please provide some more information about what you're trying to save, the code that comes before this `savefig` call.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Sundar. I've edited the question. I don't have too much context to give you anyway because I'm not doing something very complex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FrancoRiottini - Is `employment_contour` something from a package, or something you wrote? It may also be a bug in PlotlyJS - something is generating invalid JSON it seems.

Comment: Thanks for answering. `employment_contour ` is a function that I've written, that makes a contour plot of some variables. It may be a bug, yes. I will reinstall everything and see what happen, I was delaying that moment but I don't see another solution

Comment: Something to try if you can open a `PlotlyJS` plot on your computer for browser viewing: see what happens if you `display(p)` your plot rather than `savefig(p)`. This might give you error information that `savefig(p)` does not provide.

Comment: Hi Bill. `display(p)` shows the plot perfectly haha. It's kinda weird. But I've reinitiated Windows, and it is working again. Don't know what happened, it's a mystery.